# PDOException could not find driver ya modifique el archivo php.ini pero sigue marcando lo mismo es para pdo_firebird

Tags: laravel, firebird

PDOException
could not find driver

Comment: Si pero... ¿Ya apagaste el servidor y lo volviste a activar? Los cambios no se reflejan es por eso.

Comment: ya apagamos y encendimos

Comment: Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Mon Apr 26 02:06:43 2021] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_firebird (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll (%1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: aparece haci al ejecutar

Answer (score -2, accepted):

revisa por que puede haber mas de un php.ini, si mal no recuerdo la ubicacion de el php.ini actual sale en phpinfo()